# Strings from NSArray into annotation, mapkit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to populate the Title, and Subtitle using mapkit with the following lines of code.
The textItems array holds two strings.

```
NSArray *textItems = [searchString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

addAnnotation =
 [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location
                                        mTitle:[[textItems objectAtIndex:0] stringValue]
                                     mSubTitle:[[textItems objectAtIndex:1] stringValue]];
```

The app stops when it reaches the 'addAnnotation'.

If I change `mTitle:[[textItems objectAtIndex:0] stringValue]` to mTitle:`@"test"` i.e. it works fine. When I debug I can see that the data in the textItems array is present.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: nslog textitems array and with objectatindex o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `componentsSeparatedByString` method returns an array of `NSString` objects.

You are calling `stringValue` on those objects but `stringValue` applies to `NSNumber` objects--not `NSString` so you must be getting an "unrecognized selector" error.

Remove the calls to `stringValue`:

```
addAnnotation = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location 
    mTitle:[textItems objectAtIndex:0] 
    mSubTitle:[textItems objectAtIndex:1]];
```

However, it would still be a good idea to check the count before accessing those indexes in the array and use a default value if the array returns only 0 or 1 objects.

Comment: @Anne Thanks - that was the problem. Should have checked NSString Class Reference - it says it all.

Answer (score 1):

I would set a breakpoint between the first and second line you posted. When you get there, go down to the console and type "po textItems" and "po [textItems count]". They will print the array and the number of objects in the array respectively. At the very least it's a check to make sure that you're getting the number of objects in the array you expect.